# Unexpected behavior of html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

JQuery **[`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)** method takes arguments html string or a function as per it's documentation. But if I used array of jQuery objects it also works with it. How it's works there is no documentation at all.

For example :

```js
$('div').html([$('<div/>', {
  text: '1'
}), $('<div/>', {
  text: '2'
})]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

The above code binds two divs.

Is array of jQuery object equals to jQuery object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.html()` accepts jQuery object as parameter

> How it's works there is no documentation at all

This is correct. This is not thoroughly described at jQuery documentation. You would need to review the source of jQuery to be aware of this; without trying passing a jQuery, or other object, for example an array of jQuery objects to `.html()`.

See `jquery-2.2.3.js` at `5490` - `5527` for `jQuery.fn.html` function; note `if` condition and use of `.append()` at `5523` - `5525`

```
  if ( elem ) {
    this.empty().append( value );
  }
```

Comment: Is array of jQuery object equals to jQuery object?

Comment: Also there is no documentation about it

Comment: @PranavCBalan There are several omissions at jQuery documentations; features left un-described; functions available